# PHP Functions returning an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having some issues with my function which returns an array, I decided to try and use an OO approach to my php code and try to make a class with a few static functions since I decided I don't want to access it using an object. In my code, within the same class, I decided to make the following function:

```
public static function decideCategory($tweets) {

    $tweet = $tweets;

    if(in_array($tweet, self::$food)) {
        echo "\nOur " . $tweet . " is under food\n";
    } //if statements of the same nature below as well. 

}
```

Now, this function works in the sense that it does not throw an error where $food is definded as an array at the top. However, originally I simply had $food defined at the top as just a private static variable, and then I had the following function which I passed into the in_array.

```
public static function getFood()
    {
        self::$food = array("Wendys", "McDonalds", "Wendy's", "Chic Fil A", "Chic-Fil-a", "Burger", "TGI", "BBQ", "Grilling", "Wine", "Tasty", "Yum", "IHOP", "Pancakes", "Pizza", "Cake"
        ,"Baking");
        return self::$food;
    }
```

However, it would return an error saying that in_array expects an array value for its second argument, but that instead it sees that a null was passed instead. Why is that and how can I use methods to do my comparison rather than the variables themselvs. If this were Java this would be how I would do it, and as such I cannot see why php would have these issues as it appears to follow a similar logic with returns.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you trying to do here?

Comment: If you wanted to use an OO approach, then why are you trying to avoid using an object?

Comment: Although using Statics is not exactly full on OO, it still accessing it from the class name rather than just calling the function

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would error because until you call self::getFood() Self::$food is null if you have declared it as

```
static $food;
```

update your method as below

```
public static function decideCategory($tweets)
{
    $tweet = $tweets;
    $food = self::getFood();
    if(in_array($tweet, $food)) {
        echo "\nOur " . $tweet . " is under food\n";
    } //if statements of the same nature below as well. 
}
```

Comment: Or `in_array($tweet, self::getFood())`

Comment: well, I tried doing it like that originally, the self::getFood(), but it complained that it was null

Comment: @SomeStudent i have tried this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c82067e09479123b9c44dfa8b743257 and got no errors, can you try the same.